# Malformed Version Number String - Cocoapods

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

Preface: I'm a complete newb at this and was following instructions via OneSignal in order to complete this part. However, I keep running into the same problem, no matter what I try.

Goal: 
Attempting to set up push notifications via iOS. I don't have the use of a Mac at the moment so I'm using VirtualBox.

The Problem: 
I expect for the process to be completed and a file to be created, an xcworkspace file within the folder I am using a terminal on.

Instead, I get an error. Here is the full log:

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.9.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.1.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.4 (19E287)
       Xcode :  ()
         Git : git version 2.24.2 (Apple Git-127)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib
Repositories :
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
target 'OneSignalNotification?' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.11.2', '< 3.0'
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.11.2', '< 3.0'
end
```

#### Error

```
ArgumentError - Malformed version number string iOS 10
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/version.rb:47:in `initialize'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:199:in `new'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:199:in `new'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:150:in `block in compute_platform'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:146:in `each'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:146:in `compute_platform'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:43:in `compute_results'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1180:in `block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1178:in `each'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1178:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1176:in `each'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1176:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1171:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:106:in `analyze'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Malformed+version+number+string+iOS+10&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/inspector_reporter.rb:80: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
 - ArgumentError - Malformed version number string ~> 4.0
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9667 [open] [0 comments]
   4 weeks ago

/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/inspector_reporter.rb:80: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
 - Sustainability of using Github as podspec source
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10 [closed] [3 comments]
   07 Jun 2012

/Users/paulmanghan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/inspector_reporter.rb:80: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
 - Malformed version number string
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7765 [closed] [47 comments]
   26 Aug 2019

and 22 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=Malformed%20version%20number%20string%20iOS%2010&type=Issues&utf8=✓

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.4` on target `OneSignalNotification?` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
paulmanghan@iMac OneSignalNotification? %

I have tried updating Ruby, updating RMC, Cocoapods, Re-installing them all but nothing appears to work. This is as far as I can get. If it makes a difference, the guide I am following is this:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

There is a similar issue that is from 2018 and I have tried all of the solutions within that thread, to no avail. I'm running out of options now. Hopefully someone can help.

Thank you, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/blob/master/lib/cocoapods-core/version.rb

The comments at the top of the file explain that this class expects an argument 'version' that is either a String or a previously defined Version

```
# @param  [String,Version] version
#         A string representing a version, or another version.
```

And the version examples are like:

```
  # Prereleases sort between real releases (newest to oldest):
  #
  # 1. 1.0
  # 2. 1.0.b1
  # 3. 1.0.a.2
  # 4. 0.9
```

Which makes me think that you cannot pass "iOS 10" here.  I'm not sure where you're passing the iOS 10 parameter - but this doesn't appear to be a valid version.

In short - the error message is coming from a Ruby module that appears to be used for semantic versioning of a *gem* as we see from the top of the file:

```
 # It is based on the RubyGems class adapted to support head information.
  #
  # ### From RubyGems:
  #
  # The Version class processes string versions into comparable
  # values. A version string should normally be a series of numbers
  # separated by periods. Each part (digits separated by periods) is
  # considered its own number, and these are used for sorting. So for
  # instance, 3.10 sorts higher than 3.2 because ten is greater than
  # two.
```

And for whatever reason - line 23 in your 'pod' kicks off this process of passing version information through a variety of other modules, finally getting to version.rb and version.rb throws an error on what it was originally handed.

I'm not sure exactly what you should change - I can only guide you with what the error message is saying - and you are going to need to step backwards until you find the iOS 10 part (I saw an image in the guide you linked) and change that to see if you get a different output next time you install.